# AngularJS directives for 'non visual' tasks

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

There are scenarios where I find myself writing markup code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in data.Chapters">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data.Rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in data.Columns">
                {{chapter.Values[$parent.$index][$index].V}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The final binding expression can get complex, and if you imagine scenarios where `chapter.Values[$parent.$index][$index]` is a complex object and you have to access all of its properties, then those bindings get long and noisy. I wrote a simple directive that allows me to change my markup to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in data.Chapters">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data.Rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in data.Columns"
                append-context name='item'
                expression='chapter.Values[$parent.$index][$index]'>
                {{item.V}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now, after using my `append-context` directive (code omitted, but it's trivial), I can refer to my object with an *alias* (`item`) which greatly simplifies readability.

I have mixed feelings with this because the directive is not really *extending HTML* in terms of enhancing its layouting capabilities, what it really does is really related to scope management. I have other contexts where I used a similar approach to handle things like, for example, heavy redraws (transparently introducing `setTimeout` calls through specific directives), again not strictly related to HTML rendering.

Do you think it's a legitimate approach, or just a trick to solve a problem that should have been solved in a different way in the first place?

**UPDATE**

Here the mentioned directive:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('appendContext', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: function ($scope, $attrs) {
                var expression = $attrs.expression,
                    name = $attrs.name;
                $scope[name] = $scope.$eval(expression);
            }
        };
    })
```

**UPDATE 2**

@DavidChase has a good point in his comment, although I still have mixed feelings about creating a *general purpose* controller (but it's very likely it's just me). Probably this other directive is a better example:

```
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('progressive', ['$timeout', 'status', function (timer, status) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            compile : function (el, attrs, transclude) {
                return function (scope, element) {
                    status.working.start(function(working) {
                        timer(function () {
                            transclude(scope, function (node) {
                                element.append(node);
                            });
                            working.stop();
                        }, 10);
                    });
                };
            }
        };
    }])
```

In this case there is no real DOM manipulation, because I do not add anything to it, but I use a couple of external services to *transclude* the content in an "async" way, in order to slightly improve the UI experience in case of long refresh (avoiding stuck UI). As I said, I don't add anything to DOM, but I just control when things are created. Is it a good use case for a directive?

Comment: just for curiosity sake can you post the directive that you used here?

Comment: @DavidChase here you have it

Comment: so why use a directive, it doesnt seem like your modifying the DOM instead you are just augmenting the scope, which is what a controller is for to begin with no? a directive feels out of place here

Comment: Yeah, but also in this case I wasn't sure, my impression is that a controller is to implement specific logic for a specific use case, but this would be a general purpose controller with no logic, just there to augment the scope. Do you think it's ok?

Comment: "technically" speaking if your appending anything to the element thats DOM manipulation so in that case for Update 2 it makes sense to create a directive, despite it being trivial or not.. again if your just augmenting the scope use a controller

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question instead of me "polluting" the comments above (for lack of a better word).

Controllers as defined [**here**](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.mvc.understanding_controller) are used like you are using them to **augment the scope**.

> They can one add an initial state to the scope such as:

`$scope.message = 'hello'` and then use `{{message}}` in your template or view

> They can also create actions on the scope via functions such as:

- Calculations
- Decisions based on logic
- Evaluations

Essentially they do the "business logic" between view and model/data tier.

Controllers are meant to be simple/minimal otherwise create a factory or service and pass them to controllers.

Directives are for DOM manipulating and other view based changes.

Hopefully this points you into the right direction (in a roundabout way) of not using the directive in your case and using a controller or if need creating a service and then injecting into a controller.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the docs, actually reading them I'm still in doubt, at the chapter **Using Controllers Correctly** you can read *In general, a controller shouldn't try to do too much. It should contain only the business logic needed for a single view*. But in my case there's no business logic (I'm just adding aliases for cleaner markup) and I'm not tied to a single view, it's a reusable 'non business' behavior... Not sure...